# Webpack can't handle JSX even with appropiate loaders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

First of all, i know that there are various questions like this in SO. I followed them but i'm still getting an error. I'm learning React.js with gulp, and now i wanted to move to webpack to have hot code reloading on browser. I'm learning to configure webpack based on this code:

https://github.com/learncodeacademy/react-js-tutorials/tree/master/1-basic-react

When i run `webpack --watch` command, i get this error:

```
Hash: 826e21c818de1882d366
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 42ms
   [0] ./js/scripts.js 0 bytes [built] [failed]

ERROR in ./js/scripts.js
Module parse failed: C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack/src\js\scripts.js Unexpected token (4:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (4:16)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprList (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2165:22)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseSubscripts (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1741:35)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1718:17)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1573:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:727:47)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\Proyectos\react_webpack\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:404:3)
```

This is the structure of my project:

```
|-- node_modules
|   |-- //I have all the libraries listed in package.json below
|-- src
|   |-- js
|   |   |-- comments.jsx
|   |   |-- scripts.js
|   |-- index.html
|-- .babelrc
|-- package.json
|-- webpack.config.js
```

webpack.config.js

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var SRC_FOLDER = __dirname + "/src";

module.exports = {
  context: SRC_FOLDER,
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/scripts.js",
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /js\/\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      }
    ]
},
  output: {
    path: SRC_FOLDER + "/js",
    filename: "scripts.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react_webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Learn how to use webpack",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.11.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {

  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
}
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "stage-0",
        "react"
    ]
}
```

And the entry point which trows the error, scripts.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Comment, CommentsList} from 'comments';
ReactDOM.render(<CommentsList />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

I don't think is necessary to post comments.jsx, since i already tested it in my app when i was using gulp and works without problems.

What i have tried to fix it, but hasn't worked:

- Create the .babelrc file, even when i set the presets in webpack.config.js
- Execute webpack with --config flag to check if it can find the config file
- Using the same libraries used in the github repo project (when i download that source code and execute webpack --watch it works)
- Check that it founds every file (comments.jsx, scripts.js)
- Changed extension to js or jsx (and updating webpack.config.js) to check if it is because of file extension

All the problem is caused in scripts.js in this line:

```
ReactDOM.render(<CommentsList />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Exactly when < starts. It can't handle JSX even when i added necessary presets and have all dependencies.What could be happening?

Comment: I think your `RegExp` should looks like this `/\.jsx?$/`

Comment: Yeah, the test for the loader isn't correct.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My mistake. I thought that, because my js/jsx files are under /js, i should put it in the regexp. @AlexanderT., i cannot mark your comment as the answer, can you post it as an Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need remove `js\/` from `RegExp`

```
 test: /\.jsx?$/
```

because `/js\/\.jsx?$/` matches files like this

```js
 console.log(/js\/\.jsx?$/.test('js/.jsx'));
 console.log(/js\/\.jsx?$/.test('js/.js'));
```